# Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.4'

Tags: python3, postgresql, python-2.7

Getting error while installing `uniq`

Error message:

```
Downloading https://engci-maven-master.cisco.com/artifactory/api/pypi/apic-em-pypi-group/packages/86/fd/cc8315be63a41fe000cce20482a917e874cdc1151e62cb0141f5e55f711e/psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    100% |\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588| 378kB 458kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.4'


----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_cf1z03a/psycopg2/
```

Ubuntu 18.04

How can I install it correctly?

Command used:

```
pip3 install uniq==2.1.22.* --no-cache-dir --index-url=https://engci-maven-master.cisco.com/artifactory/api/pypi/apic-em-pypi-group/simple
```

Comment: Well it says it's running `python setup.py egg_info`, so presumably from what is said below that's running python3 instead of python2.7. So perhaps check with `ls -al $(which python)`. Then if it's going to python3, route the soft-link to python2.7 (temporarily) to run the script?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solutions is probably to upgrade to psycopg 2.7:

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292261:

> The problem was fixed in #489 released in psycopg 2.7. We don't have plans to backport the fix to 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is due to `pip` using Python version 3 and Ubuntu having python version 2.7 installed. Many users report errors [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/418).

The most common solution is to first use:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

**Note:** Some report success using `pip` whilst others used `pip3` as the above command does.

Read the entire link for all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing PostgreSQL 9.4 solved the problem...

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

Then I stopped and disabled the service because I didn't need it...

```
systemctl postgresql stop
systemctl postgresql disable
```

**Thanks! =D**